# Passing a collection_selection and text_field values in a form_for, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, collections, form-for

The Attraction model belongs to Destination.

I'm trying to create a new attraction (text_field :name) but also linking it to an already-created destination.  These destinations are rendered in a drop-down menu with this collection_select tag.  By clicking submit, I'm want the attraction to be created and saved in the activerecord database with the Destinations foreign key.

f.collection_select(:attraction, :destination_id, Destination.all, :id, :name) %>

The whole block looks like this at the moment:

```
<h1>New attraction</h1>
```

### Select a City

```
<%= f.collection_select(:attraction, :destination_id, Destination.all, :id, :name) %>   

<div class ="field">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

How can I save the attraction to the database with the appropriate destinaton? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use `f.collection_select()` so not sure what it is called inside the params, but lets assume for the following code that it's `params[:attraction][:destination_id]`. You can change your create action to:

```
def create
  @destination = Destination.find(params[:attraction][:destination_id])
  @attraction = @destination.attractions.build(params[:attraction])
  if @attraction.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

That's assuming that you've created a `has_many` and `belongs_to` association.

If you run into a mass-assignment error then change the first line to:

```
@destination = Destination.find(params[:attraction].delete(:destination_id))
# this will return the deleted value, and in the next line of code
# you'll have the rest of the params still available
```